# Como se hace este constructor de parametros

Tags: java

- Apuesta
- Propiedades:

  - Id de usuario, de tipo String, consultable. Identificador que del usuario que realiza la apuesta.
  - Fecha de la apuesta, de tipo LocalDateTime, consultable. Registra el momento en el que se
    realiza la apuesta.
  - Partido, de tipo PartidoFutbol(Esto viene en otra clase pero no afecta mucho), consultable. Partido para el que se realiza la apuesta.
    Introducción al diseño de tipos 11
  - Cantidad apostada, de tipo Float, consultable. Indica la cantidad que el usuario ha apostado
    en el partido.
  - Goles local, de tipo Integer, consultable. El número de goles que el apostante cree que
    marcará el equipo local.
  - Goles visitante, de tipo Integer, consultable. El número de goles que el apostante cree que
    marcará el equipo visitante.
  - Ganadora, de tipo Boolean. Derivada. Es cierta si la apuesta es ganadora. Una apuesta es
    ganadora si el número de goles del equipo local y del equipo visitante de la apuesta, coinciden
    con el número de goles del equipo local y visitante del partido.
- Constructores:

  - C1: recibe un parámetro por cada propiedad básica del tipo.
  - C2: recibe el id del usuario que realiza la apuesta, la cantidad que apuesta, los goles que cree
    que va a marcar el equipo local, los goles que cree que va a marcar el equipo visitante, la fecha
    en la que se juega el partido, los goles que ha marcado el equipo local y los goles que ha
    marcado el equipo visitante. Crea una apuesta cuya fecha es la fecha en la que se crea el
    objeto en el programa.
- Representación como cadena: La fecha de la apuesta, seguida del id del usuario que realiza la apuesta,
  el equipo local, el visitante y la cantidad apostada. “21-09-16 04:15:00:00, demoUser, Sporting GijónBarcelona,

Comment: Cuéntenos que intentó hasta ahora. Le ayudaremos a resolver dudas y/o problemas. no tareas completas.  Gracias.

Comment: Realmente necesitaba saber como probar los constructores mediante una clase que cree objetos con cada uno de los constructores definidos en cada clase y muestre las propiedades de los objetos creados por consola.       pd:gracias por la atencion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Apuesta {
    private String id;
    private LocalDateTime fecha;
    private PartidoFutbol partido;
    private float cantidadApostada;
    private int golesLocal;
    private int golesVisitante;
    private boolean ganadora;



    public Apuesta(String id, LocalDateTime fecha, PartidoFutbol partido, float cantidadApostada, int golesLocal,
            int golesVisitante, boolean ganadora) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.partido = partido;
        this.cantidadApostada = cantidadApostada;
        this.golesLocal = golesLocal;
        this.golesVisitante = golesVisitante;
        this.ganadora = ganadora;
    }

    public Apuesta(String id, float cantidadApostada, int golesLocal, int golesVisitante) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.cantidadApostada = cantidadApostada;
        this.golesLocal = golesLocal;
        this.golesVisitante = golesVisitante;

        this.fecha = fecha.now();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fecha + ", " + id + ", " + partido.getEquipoVisitante() 
                     + " - " partido.getEquipoLocal() + ": " 
                     + cantidadApostada + " €";
    }
}
```

Imagino que lo que más dificultades te trae puede ser el generar la hora actual en el segundo constructor `this.fecha = fecha.now();` porque el resto es más o menos standard.
Fíjate que asumo que tienes métodos `getEquipoVisitante()` y `getEquipoLocal()` en la clase Partido.

Comment: Si,lo que realmaente me faltaba era lo de la hora,muchas gracias por la respuesta